# How do I handle Python imports in a more 'absolute' manner?

Tags: python, import

I have a folder structure like so:

```
a
+- b.py
+- c
   +- d.py
   +- e
      +- f.py
```

`f.py` contains the function `f()`.

`d.py` contains the function `d()` and contains the line
`from e.f import f`

`b.py` has the function `b()` and contains the line
`from c.d import d`

When I try `python b.py` I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'e'`.

I can change the imports in `d.py` so that it says `from c.d.e.f import f`, which would allow me to run `b.py`, but then I can no longer run `d.py`.

This seems like a pretty obvious issue with the Python import system, so I assume there is something I can do to make this not happen.

So, is there any 'absolutely absolute' (yes I tried reading about absolute imports but from what I can tell they're just what I had above) import? Like, let's say the absolute path of `a` is `/a/`. Would something like `from $.a.c.e.f import f` be possible?

Comment: Do you want to know how to use [relative imports](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/)?

Comment: Maybe you should create a [package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages). Then you can `import a` and access `a.c.e.f.f()`

Comment: Absolute imports are the "default"; when you import a module, it must exist in a directory on the Python search path. A *relative* import involves a module name prefixed with one or more `.`; such a name is searched for not in a directory on your search path, but in the "current" package. (How the current package is defined is the important detail in understanding relative imports.)

Comment: A package is most commonly defined using a directory, but the two concepts are distinct. It's better to think in terms of packages when writing your Python code, keeping the details of how the package is defined and discovered separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An import specifying a module name that begins with an identifier is an absolute import: the top-level module must exist in a directory on your Python search path (`sys.path`). All of the imports in your current code *are* absolute imports; they are the "traditional" kind of import. The importance is in contrasting them with the alternative: *relative* imports.

An import specifying a module name that begins one or more `.` is a relative import. The first `.` refers to the current package (i.e., the package that contains the module). Any additional leading `.`s refer to the parent/grandparent/etc of the current package. Thus, in `b.py` you can write

```
from .c import d
```

which means to find the module `c` in the current package `a`, compared to

```
from c import d
```

which means to find the module `c` in your Python search path.

Likewise, you could import `b` directly from `f.py` with

```
import ...b
```

The first `.` refers to `e` (the module containing `f`), the second to `c` (the module containing `e`), the third to `a` (the module containing `c`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sys` module irrespective of the hierarchy.

```
import sys 
# Add folder_a to the system path
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/folder_a')

#Now import the python file in folder_a with filename say test1.py containing function func1
from test1 import func1

#Implement the respective functions
func1(arg1,arg2,.....)
```